# I am unable to capture the 401 response I received from Postman using React Axiom

Tags: reactjs, axios, service, fetch, vite

I have a self-developed application, where I built the backend and frontend myself. I am using React for the frontend and spring boot for the backend. When I encounter a JWT error in the endpoint I've written, I return a code and reason in the response. For example:

```
{
    "code": "1003",
    "message": "JWT expired at 2023-05-09T16:35:07Z. Current time: 2023-07-20T20:11:16Z, a difference of 6233769555 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.",
    "status": 401,
    "timestamp": "2023-07-20T23:11:19.077462"
}
```

However, I am unable to capture this error on the frontend.The browser intercepts this request and returns a statusCode of 401.Below is a screenshot demonstrating this.

[image]

The service code that I use to retrieve todos is as follows.

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/todo";

class TodoService {
  constructor(user, dispatch) {
    this.user = user;
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
    console.log(this.user);
  }

  // Function to set the headers with the authorization token
  getHeaders() {
    if (this.user && this.user.token) {
      return {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.user.token,
      };
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }

  // Function to handle the response and check for 401
  handleResponse(response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      this.dispatch(logout());
      console.log("Unauthorized request. Logging out...");
    }
    return response;
  }

  // Function to handle error response
  handleError(error) {
    console.error("API Error:", error);
    console.log(error.status    );
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  getAllTodos() {
    return axios
      .get(API_URL + "/all", { headers: this.getHeaders() })
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getUserTodos() {
    return axios
      .get(API_URL + "/userTodos", { headers: this.getHeaders() })
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getTodoById(id) {
    return axios
      .get(API_URL +"/"+ id, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  createTodo(todo) {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL, todo, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}

export default TodoService;
```

I can handle the error, but the response returned from Postman does not contain any details. Here's an example of a console log:

[image]

Why am I unable to view the status code or response within the axios error object?